# Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App Error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin, google-signin

I'm just trying [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) but I'm stuck in "Add the Google Services plugin" step... I just added the dependency they said but Android Studio' console is showing me this error:

> Could not find "com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.1.0"

I searched for info here (SO) and google but didn't find any about it.

Comment: have you added this classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3' to your application/top level build.gradle

Comment: yes I added it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually download the Google Play Services library before you add it as a dependency. In your Android SDK Manager, scroll to the bottom to the "Extras" section, and download "Google Play Services." It's also a good idea to download "Google Repository" as well.

Comment: Yep, I have downloaded it before (Google Play Services rev 26 and Google Repository 21).
Ty for the answer but you should put this on comment or explain better why it can help someone (not my case because it didn't help to me :) ).

Comment: Well if you're getting that error, it basically means what it says...that it can't find the files you're saying should be there. So there is likely something somewhere in your SDK manager that needs to be updated. I would double check to make sure all of your SDK build tools are installed and up to date, as well as the API you're targeting, plus the stuff I mentioned above. Also make sure the version number you are putting in the dependency is definitely the version you have installed.

Comment: I'm going to update all related to it and feed you back about it

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your error message again, I see you are trying to call an API called "measurement." I'm not aware of any individual API with that name, and it's not listed in the table on [this docs page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). You might want to double check you have the correct name of the API you're trying to use.

Comment: I updated all and now I'm getting this error: `Error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Missing project_info object`

Comment: Gonna try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825577/gradle-fails-building-with-missing-project-info-object)

Comment: Ok still having the error in last comment, but the first one has gone, so u got it :D

Comment: [This sounds similar to your new error.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825577/gradle-fails-building-with-missing-project-info-object)