# Android Studio Gradle error: Missing project_info object

Tags: json, android-studio, gradle

basically opening this question again because the answer is outdated, as the link now redirects to Firebase:

[Gradle fails building with "Missing project_info object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825577/gradle-fails-building-with-missing-project-info-object)

I want to attach the google-services.json file to my Android Studio project, and every time I try to download it from the developers API from Google, it gives me a json file with a large name that does't correspond to the tutorial's simple "google-services" and renaming it won't work because of this error.

Downloading it creating a new project doesn't seem possible for me now as it the [page](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) gives me another error when I click Configure a Project (I already did that before but left the project there without downloading the json file directly from there, which seems to be the problem).

Where can I safely get this file, and should I rename it or? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution is just following the link and creating the project with  [Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxDnn.png):

Then create or select a project and fill it with your app data that shoul look like this (the SHA-1 key should be found in your console log when clicking the button in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgSCV.png):

Then add the lines of code that should be in your build.gradle(app level one and project level one), editing them with notepadd. Finally you need to sync these Gradle files, in Android Studio : **File->Sync project with Gradle Files**

The tutorial is very self explatanory, but for beginners like me, this could help.